# ¿Cómo se puede "diferir" la carga de codigo javascript en una página web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando una web usando boostrap, y en una página, dependiendo de un select, muestra un formulario distinto. Estos formularios están ocultos y dependiendo del valor del select muestra el correspondiente. En principio hay 10 formularios. 
En cada formulario hay varios objetos datetimepicker (de bootstrap-datetimepicker.js). Ahora mismo unos 30.
Lo que estaba haciendo era que los iniciaba cuando se cargaba la página:

```
 $(fieldName).datetimepicker({
   language:'es',
   format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
   weekStart:1, 
   todayBtn:1,
   autoclose:1,
   todayHighlight:1,
   startView:2,
   minView:2,
   forceParse:0
 });
```

Pero claro, tarda bastante en inicializar todos los datetimepicker y hasta que no los inicializa, no se carga toda lo demás, con una sensación de usuario bastante mal ya que la página tarda mucho en mostrarse.
Yo estaba ejecutando el código dentro de:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //inicializar los datetimepicker
      $(fieldName).datetimepicker({......});
      $(fieldName-1).datetimepicker({......});
       .......
      $(fieldName-n).datetimepicker({......});
 }
```

Mi pregunta es: si hay alguna manera de poder inicializar los datetimepicker y permitir que la página siga cargando, es decir, que no espere a que se termine de inicializar todos los elementos para seguir con la carga de la página y que el usuario no tenga una sensación de que la página se carga lentamente.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias intentar cargar los formularios con AJAX, según la selección del usuario envías el parámetro del formulario que se debe cargar y luego en otra pagina recibes el parámetro y traes el formulario para mostrarlo, así solo cargas lo necesario.

Comment: Si. Estaba evitando esta opción para no tener que hacer más llamadas ajax. Gracias Joseu,